# Idiomatic way to edit and delete table row cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

Default behavior of a tableview is to highlight in blue a selected row.
I have an edit/delete (not sure on the wording yet) button that puts the table in edit mode, showing the red delete circles.

I'm unsure about how or even whether to let the user edit the text of a row. (Although until now "whether" hasn't even crossed my mind.)

Is it better to let the user add and delete items, or should I include an edit function?

If I should include an edit function, should it be triggered by the same edit function that makes the delete circles appear, or should editing be enabled by another button (limited space for buttons) or even a fancy gesture?

Answer (score 0):

I would say limiting the user to add and delete but not edit would depend on your use case and what a row of your table represents.  If it's a small piece of information (say a name) then it may be more sensible to just delete the wrong one and enter a new one rather than edit.  If the row represents some larger object, then edit would probably be a good idea.  What I would recommend to get that done, is pushing to some detail view controller when the row is tapped which would have it's own edit state and allows the user to change whatever they want with that object (like how the contacts app works).